# Out of memory Exception when using Nhibernet Flush method

Tags: asp.net, oracle

Getting out of memory exception, when try to upload large file to oracle database through NHibernet 2.1. I am getting this error when i call flush method. And i am using "NEVER" mode to flush the data. Is there any limitation in NHibernet? I can trace the error-> Error is getting generated when NHibernet try to load the data into StringBuilder it seems, how ever it is an inbuild functionality. Any help on this?..

DB column type is binaryblob

Comment: You are writing an actual file to database? Which column type did you set for corresponding column in you DBMS?

Comment: I am using binaryblob type to store into db

Comment: Yes i am writing actual file along with some page level data.